# xctest - how to test if a new view loads on a button press

Tags: ios, mocking, xctest

Just started xcode 5 and xctest. How do I test that a view loads on button press. I have programatically added method that gets called when the rightBarButtonItem is clicked

```
action:@selector(onSettingsButton)
```

and in onSettingsButton

```
-(void) onSettingsButton{
    SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

How to write xctest to ensure SettingsViewController brings up the Settings view? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an interaction test — that is, a test that checks interactions between objects. In this case, you want to test that `-pushViewController:animated:` is called on the navigation controller with a `SettingsViewController`. So we want to put a mock object into `self.navigationController` which we can ask, "Were you called as expected?"

I'll assume a simple name for the class: MyView.

The way I'd do this by hand is to Subclass and Override `navigationController`. So in my test code, I'd do something like this:

```
@interface TestableMyView : MyView
@property (nonatomic, strong) id mockNavigationController;
@end

@implementation TestableMyView

- (UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    return mockNavigationController;
}

@end
```

Now instead of creating a MyView, the test will create a TestableMyView and set its `mockNavigationController` property.

This mock can be anything, as long as it responds to `-pushViewController:animated:` and records the arguments. Here's a simple example, by hand:

```
@interface MockNavigationController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) int pushViewControllerCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *pushedViewController;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL wasPushViewControllerAnimated;
@end

@implementation MockNavigationController

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.pushViewControllerCount += 1;
    self.pushedViewController = viewController;
    self.wasPushViewControllerAnimated = animated;
}

@end
```

Finally, here's a test:

```
- (void)testOnSettingsButton_ShouldPushSettingsViewController
{
    // given
    MockNavigationController *mockNav = [[MockNavigationController alloc] init];
    TestableMyView *sut = [[TestableMyView alloc] init];
    sut.mockNavigationController = mockNav;

    // when
    [sut onSettingsButton];

    // then
    XCTAssertEquals(1, mockNav.pushViewControllerCount);
    XCTAssertTrue([mockNav.pushedViewController isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]]);
}
```

These things can be simplified by using mock object frameworks such as OCMock, OCMockito, or Kiwi's mocking. But I think it helps to start by hand first, so that you understand the concepts. Then choose the tools that help. And if you know how to do it by hand, you'll never say, "Mocking framework X doesn't do what I need! I'm stuck!"

Comment: Thank you Jon. I was hoping to get the navigationControl from the main controller, get the button (navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem) and send a press mesasge to it. Then check the current visible controller is the settingsViewController. I don't know how to press the button. I can get to it in the code. I guess the point is that I don't want to check if button press works. I assume it does, I just want to check that the right controller comes up. So is what I did using the onSettingsButton on controller not enough? Thank you for your patience !

Comment: Don't test actual button press. Instead, 1) Test that the button is connected, 2) That its target is `onSettingsButton`, and 3) Invoke `onSettingsButton` directly. Nothing more is needed, because you don't need to test Apple's code.
…Your test depends on the actual activity of pushing a view controller, which could be slow. It may not even take effect before the test finishes, because it's an actual UI change. Also your test ties you to `tipViewController`. …But even if it works, I wanted you to see the general approach of dependency injection and mocking. It'll serve you well.

Comment: what are you doing inside `[sut onSettingsButton]`?

Comment: then how the mockNavigationController have the desired outputs?

Comment: The `TestableMyView` overrides the normal `-navigationController` to return the mock.

Answer (score 1):

Found one way. Maybe there are others ..

```
- (void)testSettingsViewShowsWhenSettingsButtonIsClicked{
    [self.tipViewController onSettingsButton];
    id temp = self.tipViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController;
    XCTAssertEqual([temp class], [SettingsViewController class], @"Current controller should be Settings view controller");
}
```

First call the onSettingsButton, which is the same as clicking the button, but not really. Maybe it's okay for this simple test case? How to simulate the actual press?

Then get the current view from the tipviewcontoller which is the rootview of the app and check that it is a SettingsViewController.

Comment: Hi, I used your code for swift but my navigation controller always returns nil, can you explain why? do this happen for Objective C also?