# Test view title using XCTest

Tags: ios, xctest

I am using XCtest to test the title of a view. Trying to get into the habit of writing tests first. Setup looks like

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tipViewController = self.appDelegate.tipViewController;
    self.tipView = self.tipViewController.view;

    self.settingsViewController = self.appDelegate.settingsViewController;
    self.settingsView = self.settingsViewController.view;
}
```

The problem is "settingsViewController". I have two functions for the actual test:

```
- (void) testTitleOfMainView{
    XCTAssertTrue([self.tipViewController.title isEqualToString:@"Tip Calculator"], @"The title should be Tip Calculator");
    //why does this not work?
    //    XCTAssertEqual(self.tipViewController.title, @"Tip Calculator", @"The title should be Tip Calculator");
}

- (void) testTitleOfSettingsView{
    //make the setttings view visible
    [self.tipViewController onSettingsButton];

    //test the title
    XCTAssertTrue([self.settingsViewController.title  isEqualToString:@"Settings"], @"The title should be Settings");
}
```

The "testTitleOfMainView" works. But the "testTitleOfSettingsView fails as self.settingsViewController is nil. I can sort of understand why. The view has not been initialized as yet. So I tried sending the message to the main controller that brings the settignscontroller in view

```
[self.tipViewController onSettingsButton];
```

The settingsController is still nil. Should I be using mocks? Somebody suggested this for my other question
[xctest - how to test if a new view loads on a button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462288/xctest-how-to-test-if-a-new-view-loads-on-a-button-press)

Should I subclass the settingsview and bring it up manually? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stay away from actually loading views in a real navigation stack. Real UI interactions typically need the run loop to receive events, so they will not work in a fast unit test. So throw away your setUp code.

Instead, instantiate the view controller on its own, and have it load:

```
- (void)testTitleOfSettingsView
{
    SettingsViewController *sut = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

    [sut view];    // Accessing the view causes it to load

    XCTAssertEquals(@"Settings", sut.title);
}
```

Also, learn the various assertions that are available to you in XCTest, not just XCAssertTrue. Avoid comments in those assertions; a single assertion in a small test should speak for itself.

Comment: Thank you again Jon ! Would I ever need to test real interactions? Even so, I would mock it out I guess like you showed in the other question.

Comment: In general, don't be afraid of using real interactions as long as they're fast and don't cause persistent changes (which would mess up other tests). In other words, avoid networking, file system, or persistent databases.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am watching your youtube series on TDD. Very informational for a newbie like myself !